# in doesnt work for queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have tried to use the built in Groups system in Django to pass through whether a user is part of a group or not to the template:

```
def is_contributor(request):

    group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='contributor')

    return {
        'is_contributor': True if group in request.user.groups.all() else False
    }
```

The following will pass through False even if the user is part of the group. Specifically, if I pass through the following:

```
request.user.groups.all()
```

I get:

```
<QuerySet [<Group: contributor>]>
```

Which leads me to believe that the 'in' in this case is not working over the queryset.

Are there limitations to using in over a queryset? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just filter the user's group on that name?

```
def is_contributor(request):

    return {
        'is_contributor': request.user.groups.filter(name='contributor')
    }
```

Comment: The [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method will come in handy here.

Comment: That would make it more explicit, but an empty queryset equals to False.

Comment: Thanks both, works like a charm, using the more implicit combination